# VsCode Terminal - How to clear terminal scrollback buffer - windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

I have googled this but not found an answer. Everytime I do a new operation I get the results of older runs. The terminal selected is powershell.
when i clear the screen cls in command line it does clear the screen but after next command I get stale data. It's annoying. Is there a way to clear the buffer in Windows 10 OS

Comment: There is this setting: `Terminal > Integrated: Scrollback` You could set it to a low number nad see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I  changed from the default of 1000 to 100. It helps but doesn't allow me to start fresh. If I do Ctrl Shift P I get a commaand 'Terminal Clear' but that doesn't seem to clear the scrollback buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new with VSCode, and also just recently googled for an answer because the bug really bugs me XD but haven't found an answer so I made a way myself.

**P.S. I'm also new with Stack Overflow so I'm sorry in advanced if I suck at explaining and commenting. XD**

**P.S. I'm not really sure if it'll work with yours but you can try it because it worked for me.**

Apparently, you can **actually clear** the terminal including the scroll buffer by doing this in order:

1. Use the **Terminal: Clear** command.
2. Use the **cls** command in the terminal.

By knowing that, we can now make a keyboard shortcut for it **because we're lazy XD**.

But first, we need an extension to enable multiple commands for a key because VSCode doesn't really have a support for that.

1. Download the **multi-command** extension for VSCode.
2. Then after that, put this in your **settings.json**.

> ```
> "multiCommand.commands":[  
>  {   
>      "command": "multiCommand.clearTerminal",
>      "label": "Clear Terminal",
>      "sequence": [
>          "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
>          "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
>          {"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", "args": {"text": "cls \u000D"}}
>      ]
>  }
> ]
> ```

3. And also this, in your **keybindings.json**. You can use any key for the shortcut. **Ctrl+K doesn't work for no reason**. But you can experiment as much as you like.

> ```
> {   
>     "key": "ctrl+shift+k", 
>     "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute", 
>     "args": {"command": "multiCommand.clearTerminal"},
>     "when": "terminalFocus"
> }
> ```

The only problem is that when there are already characters in the terminal, it'll be included in the send sequence, so just press the key twice. Or can someone recommend me a solution for it cause I'm lazy. XD